# Best way to add asterisk to <mat-label> in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to add red asterisk to my mat-label.  I'm not using bootstrap.
What's the best way to add asterisk to mat-label in angular material.  I'm using angular10 and latest angular material.

code:

```
<div fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-label>Id: </mat-label>
                </div>
                <div fxFlex="20">
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-select class="form-control" formControlName="type">
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="t.code">
                                {{type.description}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="errorHandling('type', 'required')">You must select one <strong> Id
                                type </strong>
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </div>
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: @alessandro added my code here.

Comment: I followed this already: https://paulund.co.uk/add-required-asterisk-with-css.  But I would like to check to see if there is any better way.

Comment: via stylesheet is the best option, you can drive your style class by ngclass or whatever, avoid useless markup if not needed, all the best

Comment: Angular Material adds an asterisk to the label of the form field if the underlying FormControl has Validators.required for the control validators added in its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need just to add a class to your mat-label as follow:

```
<p>
  <mat-label class="asterix--before">Legacy form field</mat-label>
  <br />
  <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" />
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
```

so in your stylesheet:

```
  .asterix--before:before {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuh7ca-mensxd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)

Comment: It worked for me.  When I tried this before I got entire label red color.  The only mistake that I did was  "mat-label.required::after".  I knew what's my mistake with this.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via **`<span>`** of HTML. Add it before your **`<mat-label>`** and give it styling as you want. Refer code below.

> app.component.html

```
<div>
    <span class="asterick">*</span>
    <mat-label>Id: </mat-label>
</div>
```

> app.component.css

```
.asterick {
  color: red;
}
```

You can refer the working demo [here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-no-label-bwbcbv?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: Hi Himanshu Sing,  Thanks for your reply.  I already followed this code by using: https://paulund.co.uk/add-required-asterisk-with-css.  But I would like to check to see if there is any better option than this.  Please let me know if you know any other better way than this.